# Почему не работают пути?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Имеется такой конфиг:

```js
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const PATHS = {
 src: path.join(__dirname, './src'),
 dist: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
 js: 'js/bundle.js',
 css: 'css/style.css',
}

module.exports = {
 externals: {
  paths: PATHS,
 },
 entry: PATHS.src,
 output: {
  path: PATHS.dist,
  filename: PATHS.js,
  publicPath: 'dist/'
 },
 module: {
  rules: [
  {
   test: /\.js$/,
   loader: 'babel-loader',
   exclude: '/node_modules/',
  }, 
  {
   test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
   loader: 'file-loader',
   options: {
    name: '[name].[ext]'
   }
  },
  {
   test: /\.less$/,
         use: [
           {
            loader: 'style-loader',
           },
           {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
           }, 
           {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
             sourceMap: true,
            }
           },
           {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: {
             sourceMap: true,
             config:  {
              path: 'postcss.config.js',
             }
            }
           },
           {
            loader: "less-loader",
            options: {
             sourceMap: true,
            }
           }
         ]
  }]
 },
   plugins: [
     new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
       filename: PATHS.css,
     }),
     new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      hash: false,
      template: `${PATHS.src}/index.html`,
      filename: './index.html',
     }),
     new CopyPlugin([
      {
         from: 'src/fonts',
         to: 'fonts',
       },
      ])
   ],
}
```

В этой части кода, судя по всему, не работают пути

```
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    hash: false,
    template: `${PATHS.src}/index.html`,
    filename: './index.html',
  }),
```

> ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Create\Create-s\src\index.html' in 'C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Create\Create-s'

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По какой причине такое может происходить?

Comment: а в этой папке есть этот файл?

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi Вот ради интереса попробовал убрать опцию `mode`, у меня вызвало ошибку, но правда другую. Попробуйте все же установить конфиг webpack-а `mode`, у вас этой опции не видно.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, это базовый конфиг, есть еще девелоп конфиг и билд

Comment: @Grundy, действительно не было файла, но теперь просто не открывается этот index.html и он не переноситься в dist